# how focus travel in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a javafx stage like this
[image]

As normal, I expect when user enter text and press tab key, it will focus to next text field for input. But my case is: when I enter FullName and press tab it will focus on Email field then Username, Password, Confirm Password.

What is wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "move" the focus, it will go to the next child with [`focusTraversable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty) set to `true`.

Since the order of the children is not important for their placement in `GridPane`, this can lead to a focus traversal order, that is independent from `Node` placement in the layout.

In your screenshot you can see that the `TextField` in cell `(1, 5)` is added before the `TextField` in cell `(1,2)`. To fix this, simply reorder the (focus traversable) children of the `GridPane` ascending by row index using the Hierarchy View.